# Animate show of UITableView HeaderView when button pressed (swift)

Tags: uitableview, animation, swift

I have created a UIView "headerView" which acts as the tableHeaderView in my UITableView.

I would like to have this originally hidden and when a button is pressed it will slide onto the screen from behind the Navigation bar, also pushing down the TableView.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.resetShowGroups()
}

private func resetShowGroups() {

    var topFrame = self.headerView.frame
    topFrame.origin.y -= topFrame.size.height
    self.headerView.frame = topFrame

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
}
```

By setting the tableHeaderView to nil to disappears at the start.

When the button is pressed the following is called to try and slide the headerView onto screen:

```
func displayGroupPicker() {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        if (!self.showGroups) {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView
        } else {
            self.resetShowGroups()
        }

        self.showGroups = !self.showGroups

        }, completion: { finished in
            println("Done")
    })

}
```

This code is as close as I can get. It appears ok but because it's set to nil when hiding it disappears before the slide animation so looks naff.

Spent way to long on this and have exhausted my googling skills.

Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem.

Instead of animating the tableHeaderView in the UITableViewController I created a UIViewController and placed both the UITableView and my SlideView in the UIView of the UIViewController.

I could then animate my SlideView independently of the UITableView, sliding On and Off screen when needed.